# How do I set Grove GPS to use A-GPS?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, c, tinygps

I am using a grove GPS http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove_-_GPS

I attached the GPS to Serial1 of Arduino Mega 2560.

The baudrate of the GPS is set to 9600.

Library wise, I am using TinyGps to parse the GPS data.

The GPS receiver can only get a valid data if it can see a clear sky.

I read uBlox documentation and it states that I can use A-GPS.

So, my question is, how do I actually set the Grove GPS that is attached to my Mega, to use A-GPS?

Answer (score 2):

A-GPS uses a network connection to download GPS almanac and ephemeris data to enable satellites to be located faster. Otherwise the GPS device has to wait for the data to be sent by a satellite, which may take up to 12.5 minutes. Alternatively, the GPS device can send noise GPS data to an assistance server which will process it and send back a fix.

A-GPS requires a network connection to an A-GPS server. You can't just 'turn it on'. There are some modules out there that combine GPS with a 3G modem which do A-GPS automatically.

Comment: In other words, are you saying that I cannot use A-GPS on the grove GPS? I do have the official GSM/GPRS shield attached to the mega too on top of the Grove GPS However.

Comment: You would have to find a server, see http://www.u-blox.com/en/assisted-gps.html

Comment: But then, how do I configure the Grove GPS on the arduino to use A-GPS?

Comment: I'm guessing it will be in the datasheet or app note for the UBlox chipset. A lot of work required.

Comment: If you connect your Grove GPS to a Raspberry Pi, it keeps track of the ephemeris data, so after rebooting you can find a signal quicker. eg. using `gpsd` package. If your Pi is last used in a different country, the stored data wont make sense, so it will have to wait for fresh data sent by the satellite anyway